# How to initialize out-of-proc COM server using Excel Add-in

Tags: excel, com

I'm trying to build a out-of-proc RTD COM server excel. But I'm not sure how can COM EXE be initialized when excel instance is opened by user. Thus I need to initialize only once instance of COM EXE if user opens multiple excel instances.

Can you please suggest a way of achieving above requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add reference of that tlb.
2. create object. nothing different from usual style.